# 'allegro_init()' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, linux, allegro5

Guys I am trying to install the allegro 5 library on Ubuntu 11.04. The tutorial I followed for doing [is](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Install_Allegro5_From_SVN/Linux/Debian) this.
Now I had some errors while installing the libraries in the first attempt but I could get over them and install the libraries properly. The problem is that when I try to run my sample code

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 

{
allegro_init(); 

install_keyboard(); 

set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT, 640,480,0,0); 

readkey();

return 0; 
}

END_OF_MAIN()
```

I get errors like

```
ajinkya@ajinkya-8I945GZME-RH:~/random$ g++ example.cpp -o example -lalleg
example.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
example.cpp:7:15: error: ‘allegro_init’ was not declared in this scope
example.cpp:9:19: error: ‘install_keyboard’ was not declared in this scope
example.cpp:11:15: error: ‘GFX_AUTODETECT’ was not declared in this scope
example.cpp:11:42: error: ‘set_gfx_mode’ was not declared in this scope
example.cpp:13:10: error: ‘readkey’ was not declared in this scope
example.cpp: At global scope:
example.cpp:18:13: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion at end   of input
```

I have all the main header file in `/usr/include/allegro5`.

Comment: Allegro 5 is not backward compatible with Allegro 4. You are writing Allegro 4 code, using an Allegro 5 header, and linking against Allegro 4. Tip: if the functions are prefixed with al_, then you are looking at an Allegro 5 tutorial. You should be using Allegro 5 for new projects.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check that those methods actually exist in the header file ?

It seems that you are using Allegro 4 API instead of Allegro 5 :
see http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Allegro_5_Tutorial/Displays

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand how the examples provided with the package are out of date and don't work. So the basic code is working but still have some problems like why do I have to use `gcc -Wall lesson1.cpp `pkg-config --libs allegro-5.0`` and also [this](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Basic_tutorial_on_loading_and_showing_images) example gives errors like ` undefined reference to `al_show_native_message_box'`

Comment: Maybe the documentation is not up-to-date with the latest code.The undefined reference is due to missing library in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or you may have to update the `ld.so.conf` file.

Where did you find the lesson1.cpp file?

Comment: Source code used in the file lesson1.cpp http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Basic_tutorial_on_loading_and_showing_images.

Comment: @Ajinkya, Allegro 5 is modular. e.g., In that example, you must link against allegro, allegro_image, and allegro_native_dialog libs.

Comment: found the solution on this [link](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Compiling_Allegro_Programs) and the programs are working fine.